# Unknown process named 573f2a55-2573-4c9f-ad5d-9d5d-9dbcf14c9281.exe during startup

Tags: windows-xp, boot, process

during startup of up my computer (Windows XP SP3) I had a look on the TaskManager, I noticed a process named `573f2a55-2573-4c9f-ad5d-9d5d-9dbcf14c9281.exe`.

It took 5600kB of memory and 0% CPU at that time, and went away a second later (I was able to get it's name because I quickly grabbed a screenprint).

Any idea what it is about? Could it perhaps be a temporary process of KeePass.exe?

Thanks, Jan-Hendrik

Answer (score 0):

It certainly looks suspicious. If I were you, I would upload it to this Web site, https://www.metascan-online.com/en, which coordinates scan of the said file on more than 40 anti-virus scanners. There is also a plethora of online scanners, provided for free. All you have to do is to Google the words *online anti virus scan*. Some of these sites (the top ones are all reputable) will perform a scan of your whole system, not just of that file.

Welcome to Windows Security 101.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) utility,find out the location